# What does $\exists !x(P\rightarrow Q(x))$ translate to? A paradox?

Tags: first-order-logic

Does it translate to $$\exists x\forall y((P\rightarrow Q(x))\land ((P\rightarrow Q(y))\rightarrow y=x)),\text{ or}$$ $$\exists x\forall y(P\rightarrow (Q(x)\land (Q(y)\rightarrow y=x)))?$$

$x$ is not free in $P$.

**Note:** They, I’m pretty sure, are not logically equivalent. But they being not equivalent implies that $\exists !x(P\rightarrow Q(x))$ is not equivalent to $P\rightarrow \exists !xQ(x)$, which is absurd as it is allowed in prenex conversion.

Comment: Assuming the domain of $Q$ has more than one element, it becomes $P \wedge \exists ! Q(x)$. The failure of the conversion isn't really a surprise since $\exists !$ is a "composite".

Comment: @Ian Can you please elaborate? Not getting it.

Comment: Looking at this particular case, the point is that if $P$ is false then $P \rightarrow Q(x)$ is true for all $x$, which breaks the unique existence if the domain of $Q$ has more than one element. More generally the issue here is that although $\exists$ distributes over $\vee$, $\exists!$ does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the meaning is the first one.

What about your assertion

> $\exists !x(P\rightarrow Q(x))$ is not equivalent to $P\rightarrow \exists !xQ(x)$

What if $P$ is false and $Q(x)$ is "$x = 0$".  [Certainly $\exists ! x Q(x)$ is true.  But so what?]  Then $P \rightarrow S$ is true for any $S$.  In particular $P \rightarrow Q(x)$ is true for all $x$, and thus $\exists !x(P\rightarrow Q(x))$ is **false** because uniqueness fails.  On the other hand, as noted, $P \rightarrow S$ is true for any $S$, so in particular $P\rightarrow \exists !xQ(x)$ is **true**.

So you are correct, they are not equivalent.  So I guess your next assertion

> which is absurd

is wrong.