# What is the formal translation of this statement?

Tags: first-order-logic

Statement: For each $x$ in $X$, there exists a unique $y$ in $Y$ such that $(x,y)\in f$.

Which is the correct translation?

- $\forall x\exists !y(x\in X\rightarrow (y\in Y\land (x,y)\in f)$
- $\forall x(x\in X\rightarrow \exists !y(y\in Y\land (x,y)\in f)$
- $\forall x\exists y(x\in X\rightarrow (y\in Y\land (x,y)\in f)\land\forall x\forall y\forall z((x,y)\in f\land (x,z)\in f\rightarrow y=z)$

Are any of these equivalent? Also please consider the case when $Y$ is not singleton.

---

You might want to have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3290890/673223).

Comment: The first one would require either that the whole universe is $X$ or that there is exactly one thing in the universe. The other two formulas are correct.

Comment: @Berci Are second and third equivalent?